# Estimating mean of Normal with unknown variance and then predict the future observation

Tags: probability, self-study, bayesian, normal-distribution, t-distribution

I am trying to estimate population mean of 9 observations when the variance is unknown. I marginalized the posterior and understand that the t- distribution would give me the distribution of population mean. I am stuck at this point. Normally, If I had to estimate some thing  I would generate 1000 or more random samples of the given distribution and then generate point or interval estimates for it's values. But the T-distribution has confused me. Matlab's tpdf generates only 8 samples, but when I sum them up they do not add up to 1 which looks weird so is it generating actual values? If these are actual values then where is the distribution? how do I estimate mean from it (Substitute these values in the standardization formula to find values of mean?).

PS: I have been studying stats recently and though I understand the mathematical part of it, I feel miserable when doing simulation in matlab. So I would appreciate any pointers twards learning the computational side of it.

EDIT: I understand the mathematical or derivation part of it. It is the computational simulation that confuses me. I use tpdf for using t distribution but it needs data and degree of freedom. and then how do I go about finding the point estimate of mean in matlab. Aso tpdf needs to be translated towards my data values.

Comment: slef-study?! Please add the tag. And explain more clearly why the $t$ distribution confuses you. It has a mean that you can use as an estimator and you can produce a credible interval by using the t pdf.

Comment: Why should they add to 1?

Comment: Shouldn't a probability distribution integrate to 1?

Comment: Values sampled from a distribution are not (usually) probabilities, and even if they were, a set of sampled probabilities do not form a probability distribution. Consider if they did - then the first value (itself a sample of size 1) would have to be "1" to make that initial "distribution" integrate to 1, so all subsequent values would have to be "0". You seem to have a very mistaken notion of what's going on, but there are several errors at once, so it's difficult to start untangling your notions.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from our [Bayesian Essentials with R](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441922865) book,

> if $\mathscr{D}_n$ denotes a normal
>   $\mathscr{N}\left(\mu,\sigma^{2}\right)$ sample of size $n$, if $\mu$
>   has a prior equal to a $\mathscr{N}\left(0,\sigma^{2}\right)$
>   distribution, and $\sigma^{-2}$ an exponential $\mathscr{E}(1)$
>   distribution, the posterior is given by \begin{align*}
>  \pi((\mu,\sigma^2)|\mathscr{D}_n) &\propto
>  \pi(\sigma^2)\times\pi(\mu|\sigma^2)\times
>  f(\mathscr{D}_n|\mu,\sigma^2)\\
>         & \propto  (\sigma^{-2})^{1/2+2}\,
>             \exp\left\{-(\mu^2 + 2)/2\sigma^2\right\}\\
>         & \times
>         (\sigma^{-2})^{n/2}\,\exp \left\{-\left(n(\mu-\overline{x})^2 + s^2 \right)/2\sigma^2\right\} \\
>        &\propto (\sigma^2)^{-(n+5)/2}\exp\left\{-\left[(n+1)
>             (\mu-n\bar x/(n+1))^2+(2+s^2)\right]/2\sigma^2\right\}\\
>        &\propto (\sigma^2)^{-1/2}\exp\left\{-(n+1)[\mu-n\bar x/(n+1)]^2/2\sigma^2\right\}\,.\\
>         &\times (\sigma^2)^{-(n+2)/2-1}\exp\left\{-(2+s^2)/2\sigma^2\right\}\,.
>  \end{align*} Therefore, the posterior on $\theta$ can be decomposed as
>   the product of an inverse gamma distribution on $\sigma^2$,
>   $$\mathscr{IG}((n+2)/2,[2+s^2]/2)$$ which is the distribution of the
>   inverse of a gamma $$\mathscr{G}((n+2)/2,[2+s^2]/2)$$ random variable
>   and, conditionally on $\sigma^2$, a normal distribution on $\mu$,
>   $$\mathscr{N} (n\bar x/(n+1),\sigma^2/(n+1)).$$ The marginal posterior
>   in $\mu$ is then a Student's $t$ distribution $$ \mu|\mathscr{D}_n
>  \sim \mathscr{T}\left(n+2,n\bar
>  x\big/(n+1),(2+s^2)\big/(n+1)(n+2)\right)\,, $$ with $n+2$ degrees of
>   freedom, a location parameter proportional to $\bar x$ and a scale
>   parameter almost proportional to $s$.

From this distribution, you get the expectation $n\bar x/(n+1)$ that acts as your point estimator of $\mu$. And a credible interval on $\mu$
$$\left(n\bar x/(n+1)-((2+s^2)/(n+1)(n+2))^{1/2}q_{n+2}(\alpha),n\bar x/(n+1)+((2+s^2)/(n+1)(n+2))^{1/2}q_{n+2}(\alpha)\right)$$where $q_{n+2}(\alpha)$ is the $t_{n+1}$ quantile.

Comment: Hey thanks, probably I wasn't clear enough. I understand the derivation of it. It is the computational part that confuses me. I mean if I have say 10 data samples. Now how do I estimate population mean using matlab?

Comment: You have all the statistical elements above, thus only to replace the three parameters of the Student't density with the values obtained from your sample. **If this is a matlab question, it should be asked on Stack Overflow, not here.**

Comment: Not specifically matlab but any computational method. How would it be done in practice? For example, matlab can generate random numbers from a t distribution based on degree of freedom provided but how would that correspond to my data? I mean [5 6 8] and [56 54 57] both have 2 degree of freedom but their means are in very different range.

Comment: Why would you need a random generator? If I have $n=10$ observations with $\bar x=2.3$ and $s^2=312$, the posterior on $\mu$ is a $t(12,2.09,2.38)$ distribution. End of the story.